# Best method for importing configurable products into Magento

Tags: magento

What is the best way to import configurable products into Magento from CSV.  I have seen a few different methods:

- Direct MySQL statements
- Using Magento Objects
- Data Flow

Can anyone advise me on the best method for this?

Answer (score 7):

Check out Magmi. It's amazing.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, The best option as I know is the **Magento Mass Importer (MAGMI)**. Its ***not a module*** for Magento but operates ***seperatly***.. Uses direct SQL to manipulated data, and have nice re-indexing, handsome features.

It's actually **FREE** Indeed! Take a look!

Here are some important links and documentation

**Download Link**
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

**Wiki Page**
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

**Installation and Configuring Tips**
http://www.phpro.be/news/magmi-magento-mass-importer

**Some Pros and Cons**
http://fabrizioballiano.net/2011/04/19/magmi-the-best-magento-importer/

**An article admiring the project**
http://benfrain.com/magmi-the-best-way-to-import-into-magento/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much your time is worth, but I found this great module for $100 which allows you to import configurable products through advanced import.  I have been using it for a week and seems to work really well.

http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using Magento objects, as I can reuse that script later when the database layout changes. Also, it's much easier not having to deal with looking up column IDs beforehand.

Data Flow will not accomplish what you are looking for AFAIK, as it doesn't support linking the simple products to the configurable ones.