# How to import configurable products and associate simple products by csv

Tags: magento, csv, import, configurable, associate

I need to import some configurable products and I already tried to use many types of tables and try to follow different methods as these:

[Link 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/import_export/how_to_automatically_import_simple_grouped_and_configurable_products), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483530/best-method-for-importing-configurable-products-into-magento), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161432/importing-configurable-products-in-magento-from-csv), [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527878/how-to-import-configurable-product-through-csv-in-magento), [Link 5](http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2012/11/import-configurable-products-in-magento)

It works just for import configurable products but don't associate simple products don't about the method that I tried to use.

I need a help please, thanks for attention

Answer (score 0):

You can following the document at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-configurable-products